# wxPython for image and buttons (resizable)

Tags: python, image, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to put such an image in a `wx.Panel` :

- The animals should be "buttons" so that if I click on them, their image changes, and if I reclick, the image returns to normal (thus the animals can be considered as simple `BitmapToggleButtons`, as suggested by another question here on SO)
- This panel should be resized/rescaled (all all the children images / togglebuttons too!) keeping the aspect ratio, if the parent `wx.Panel` is resized to something smaller for example (like would do the standard *Windows Photo Viewer* : http://res1.windows.microsoft.com/resbox/en/windows%207/main/7eaf462a-86dd-42d2-a789-7413f5472dae_63.jpg)

I am still a bit lost on : **how to implement such a *clickable* (with toggle buttons) and *rescalable* Canvas?**

[image]

**Edit** : I started with something fruitful here [Rescale image when parent is resized in wxPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369877/rescale-image-when-parent-is-resized-in-wxpython), but now I'm totally stuck about how to continue (detect clicks, update buttons with direct DC Painting ?), that's why the bounty.

Comment: Should I use `FloatCanvas` for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with :

```
import wx
from floatcanvas import FloatCanvas

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyPanel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

        # add a canvas
        self.Canvas = FloatCanvas.FloatCanvas(self, BackgroundColor = "LIGHT GREY")
        self.Canvas.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
        self.sizer.Add(self.Canvas, -1, flag=wx.EXPAND)

        # add a toggle button
        image_dis = wx.Image('file_disabled.png')
        image_ena = wx.Image('file_enabled.png')
        img_dis = self.Canvas.AddScaledBitmap(image_dis, (x,-y), Height=image_dis.GetHeight(), Position = 'tl')
        img_ena = self.Canvas.AddScaledBitmap(image_ena, (x,-y), Height=image_ena.GetHeight(), Position = 'tl')
        img_dis.other = img_ena
        img_ena.other = img_dis
        img_ena.Visible = False

        # bind the toggle button event 
        img_dis.Bind(FloatCanvas.EVT_FC_LEFT_UP, self.OnToggle)
        img_ena.Bind(FloatCanvas.EVT_FC_LEFT_UP, self.OnToggle)

    def OnToggle(self, button):
        button.other.Visible = True
        button.Visible = False
        self.Canvas.Draw(True)

    def OnSize(self, event):
        event.Skip()
        wx.CallLater(1, self.Canvas.ZoomToBB)
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to implement your own hit testing, i.e. be able to determine where each animal is -- this is the difficult part and there is really nothing in wxWidgets to help you with this. The rest is relatively simple, you might even be able to use the existing [wxMouseEventsManager](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_mouse_events_manager.html) to avoid writing the boilerplate code yourself (but if you can't, you can at least look at its implementation, which is done entirely in wxWidgets itself, to see what you need to do).

Comment: I wanted to create each animal as a `BitmapToggleButton`, then it's very easy to toggle and update the images.

The real problem for me is : how to rescale all (background image + each animal's buttons) when the parent Panel is resized...

Comment: If I was doing this, I would definitely go with drawing the whole thing and handling the mouse events myself.  The need to rescale the whole thing would make positioning actual toggle buttons a pain.  Consider that if you resize the canvas to exactly half the size, any animal "button" which has an edge on an odd-numbered pixel *cannot* be positioned correctly, since it would have to now be at a half-pixel position, which I don't think you can do in wx (to my knowledge).  You have few enough animals that you should be able to get away without any fancy stuff like quadtrees or the like.

Comment: how to redraw an existing StaticBitmap with a smaller size for example? Should I redo a new call of StaticBitmap ?  Then at the end, I will have thousands of StaticBitmap, won't I ?

Comment: Again, using standalone controls for this is just not a good idea, you should draw the picture directly and process the events yourself. An approach based on using `BitmapToggleButton` simply won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much of this is already written, you may want to take a look at FloatCanvas (it's in the wxPython library).

If you have most of the code-base done, you can use a hit test, which is rather simple. Just make a dictionary with the [x][y] coordinates as keys which has the the BitmapTogglebutton as its value.

Here's some code that does something similar (it's been a while since I've used wxPython so it may not be 100%):

```
def onLeftDown( event ):
    x,y = event.GetX(), event.GetY()
    hitmap_x = hitmap.get(x,None)
    if hitmap_x:
        btn = hitmap_x.get(y, None)
    ...stuff with btn like toggles
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]
[image]
[image]

I made some code for practice recently. It may somehow match with your requirement.
Code is ugly and mess because I'm a newcomer to python.

Support:

1. image on the backgroud draggable
2. image animating with double-click
3. background and image on it resizeable

Notice:

1. you need have pygame to run the code
2. you can load real image by replacing PyGamePseudoImage()
3. image coordinate adjustment is not smooth enough while zoom in/out

Code:

```
import wx
import pygame

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE =  (  0,   0, 255)
GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)
RED =   (255,   0,   0)

pygame.font.init()
try:
    regular_font_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "Vera.ttf")
    bold_font_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "VeraBd.ttf")

    # Check for cx_Freeze
    #
    if "frozen" in sys.__dict__.keys() and sys.frozen:

        regular_font_file = os.path.join(sys.path[1], "Vera.ttf")
        bold_font_file = os.path.join(sys.path[1], "VeraBd.ttf")

    BIG_FONT = pygame.font.Font(regular_font_file, 30)
    SMALL_FONT = pygame.font.Font(regular_font_file, 12)
    BOLD_FONT = pygame.font.Font(bold_font_file, 12)

except:
    # TODO: log used font: pygame.font.get_default_font()
    #print("Could not load {0}".format(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "Vera.ttf")))
    BIG_FONT = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)
    SMALL_FONT = BOLD_FONT = pygame.font.Font(None, 20)


class PyGamePseudoImage():
    def __init__(self, size, color):
        self.screen = pygame.Surface(size, 0, 32)
        self.screen.fill(color)

    def getImage(self):
        return self.screen

class __MouseMixin:

    def onLeftUp(self, event):
        pass

    def onLeftDown(self, event):
        pass

    def onLeftDClick(self, event):
        pass

    def onRightUp(self, event):
        pass

    def onRightDown(self, event):
        pass

    def onDragging(self, event):
        pass

    def onMouseEnter(self, event):
        pass

    def OnMouseHandler(self, event):
        event.Skip()

        if event.LeftUp():
            self.onLeftUp(event)
        elif event.LeftDown():
            self.onLeftDown(event)
        elif event.LeftDClick():
            self.onLeftDClick(event)
        elif event.RightUp():
            self.onRightUp(event)
        elif event.RightDown():
            self.onRightDown(event)
        elif event.Dragging() and event.LeftIsDown():
            self.onDragging(event)

        pass


class DragSprite(__MouseMixin, pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    SPRITE_BUTTON, SPRITE_TRANSPORTER = range(2)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.is_select = 0
        self.lastPos = 0
        self.lastUpdate = 0
        self.parent = parent

    def setLastPos(self, pos):
        self.lastPos = pos

    def move(self, pos):
        dx = pos[0] - self.lastPos[0]
        dy = pos[1] - self.lastPos[1]
        self.lastPos = pos
        center = (self.rect.center[0] + dx, self.rect.center[1] + dy)
        self.rect.center = center
        return

    def isSelected(self):
        return self.is_select

    def setSelect(self, is_select):
        self.is_select = is_select
        return

    def update(self, current_time):
        return

def drawBoader(image, rect):
    W,H = (rect.width, rect.height)
    yellow = (255, 255, 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(image, yellow, (0,0,W-2,H-2), 2)

class ButtonSprite(DragSprite):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, initPos=(0,0), width=50, height=50, dicts=None):
        DragSprite.__init__(self, parent)
        self.type = DragSprite.SPRITE_BUTTON
        self.resourceCfgDict = dicts
        self.imageResource = {}
        self.status = 0
        self.index = 0

        self.parent = parent
        self.initPos = (initPos[0], initPos[1])
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.rectOnLoad = pygame.Rect(initPos, (width, height))
        self.rect = self.rectOnLoad.copy()

        self.operationOn = None
        self.operationOff = None

        self.operationDic = {"on": self.getOperationOnItem, "off": self.getOperationOffItem}
        self.guiCfg = None

        for dic in dicts:
            self.loadImgResource(dic)

        self.setCurrentResource("off")

    def getOperationOnItem(self):
        return self.operationOn

    def getOperationOffItem(self):
        return self.operationOff

    def loadImgResource(self, dict):
        """
            load image with pygame lib
        """
        key = dict[0]
        file_name = dict[1]

        #image_file = pygame.image.load(file_name) #use this to load real image
        image_file = PyGamePseudoImage((500,500), file_name).getImage()
        imagedata = pygame.image.tostring(image_file, "RGBA")
        imagesize = image_file.get_size()
        imageSurface = pygame.image.fromstring(imagedata, imagesize , "RGBA")

        self.imageResource[key] = (file_name, imageSurface)

    def resizeResource(self, src, size):
        return pygame.transform.smoothscale(src, size)

    def setCurrentResource(self, status):
        self.currentStatus = status
        self.imageOnLoad = self.resizeResource(self.imageResource[status][1], (self.width, self.height))
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.imageOnLoad, (self.rect.width, self.rect.height))

    def switchResource(self, index):
        self.setCurrentResource(index)

    def onZoomUpdate(self, zoomRatio):
        parentRect = pygame.Rect(self.parent.GetRect())
        dx = self.rectOnLoad.centerx - parentRect.centerx
        dy = self.rectOnLoad.centery - parentRect.centery

        self.rect.centerx = parentRect.centerx + dx*zoomRatio
        self.rect.centery = parentRect.centery + dy*zoomRatio

        self.rect.height = self.imageOnLoad.get_rect().height * zoomRatio
        self.rect.width = self.imageOnLoad.get_rect().width * zoomRatio

        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.imageOnLoad, (self.rect.width, self.rect.height))

    def update(self, current_time, ratio):
        if self.isSelected():
            drawBoader(self.image, self.image.get_rect())
        else:
            pass
            #self.image = self.imageOnLoad.copy()

    def onRightUp(self, event):
        print "onRightUp"
        event.Skip(False)
        pass

    def onLeftDClick(self, event):
        if self.currentStatus == "on":
            self.setCurrentResource("off")
        elif self.currentStatus == "off":
            self.setCurrentResource("on")

        return

    def move(self, pos):
        DragSprite.move(self, pos)

        parentRect = pygame.Rect(self.parent.GetRect())
        centerDx = self.rect.centerx - parentRect.centerx
        centerDy = self.rect.centery - parentRect.centery

        self.rectOnLoad.centerx = parentRect.centerx + centerDx/self.parent.zoomRatio
        self.rectOnLoad.centery = parentRect.centery + centerDy/self.parent.zoomRatio


class MyHmiPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID):
        wx.Window.__init__(self, parent, ID)
        self.parent = parent
        self.hwnd = self.GetHandle()
        self.size = self.GetSizeTuple()
        self.size_dirty = True
        self.rootSpriteGroup = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.Update, self.timer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
        self.fps = 60.0
        self.timespacing = 1000.0 / self.fps
        self.timer.Start(self.timespacing, False)
        self.previous_time = 0
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSE_EVENTS, self.OnMouse)

        self.selectedSprite = None

        self.zoomRatio = 1
        self.background = None
        self.bgRect = None
        self.backgroundOnUpdate = None
        self.bgRetOnUpdate = None

        self.loadBackground()
        self.addTestSprite()

    def loadBackground(self):
        #self.background = pygame.image.load(image_file) #use this to load real image
        self.background = PyGamePseudoImage((500,500), (255, 0, 0)).getImage()
        self.bgRect = self.background.get_rect()
        self.backgroundOnUpdate = self.background.copy()
        self.bgRetOnUpdate = self.bgRect.copy()

    def resizeUpdateBackground(self):
        self.bgRect.center = self.screen.get_rect().center
        self.bgRetOnUpdate = self.bgRect.copy()

    def zoomUpdateBackground(self, zoomRatio):
        self.bgRetOnUpdate.width = self.bgRect.width * zoomRatio
        self.bgRetOnUpdate.height = self.bgRect.height * zoomRatio
        self.bgRetOnUpdate.width = self.bgRect.width * zoomRatio
        self.bgRetOnUpdate.center = self.screen.get_rect().center
        self.backgroundOnUpdate = pygame.transform.scale(self.background, (self.bgRetOnUpdate.width, self.bgRetOnUpdate.height))

    def drawBackground(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.backgroundOnUpdate, self.bgRetOnUpdate)

    def addTestSprite(self):
        #self.rootSpriteGroup.add(ButtonSprite(self, initPos=(100, 100), width=100, height=100, dicts= [('on', btn_red_on), ('off', btn_red_off)]))
        #self.rootSpriteGroup.add(ButtonSprite(self, initPos=(200, 200), width=100, height=100, dicts= [('on', btn_red_on), ('off', btn_red_off)]))
        self.rootSpriteGroup.add(ButtonSprite(self, initPos=(100, 100), width=100, height=100, dicts= [('on', GREEN), ('off', BLUE)]))
        self.rootSpriteGroup.add(ButtonSprite(self, initPos=(200, 200), width=100, height=100, dicts= [('on', GREEN), ('off', BLUE)]))

    def Update(self, event):
        self.Redraw()
        return

    def Redraw(self):
        if  self.size[0] == 0  or  self.size[1] == 0:
            return

        if self.size_dirty:
            self.screen = pygame.Surface(self.size, 0, 32)
            self.resizeUpdateBackground()
            self.size_dirty = False

        self.screen.fill((0,0,0))
        self.drawBackground(self.screen)

        w, h = self.screen.get_size()
        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        self.previous_time = current_time
        self.rootSpriteGroup.update(current_time, self.zoomRatio)
        self.rootSpriteGroup.draw(self.screen)

        s = pygame.image.tostring(self.screen, 'RGB')  # Convert the surface to an RGB string
        #img = wx.ImageFromData(self.size[0], self.size[1], s)  # Load this string into a wx image
        img = wx.ImageFromData(w, h, s)  # Load this string into a wx image

        #if img.IsOk() is not True:
           # return
        bmp = wx.BitmapFromImage(img)  # Get the image in bitmap form
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)  # Device context for drawing the bitmap
        dc = wx.BufferedDC( dc)
        dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, 1)  # Blit the bitmap image to the display


    def checkCollide(self, event):
        x , y = (event.GetX(),event.GetY())

        mousePoint = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
        mousePoint.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 1, 1)
        copoint = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(mousePoint, self.rootSpriteGroup, None)

        if copoint:
            copoint = copoint[-1]

        return copoint

    def removeSelectedSprite(self):
        if self.selectedSprite:
            self.selectedSprite.setSelect(0)
            self.selectedSprite = None

    def setNewSelectedSprite(self, sprite):
        self.removeSelectedSprite()
        sprite.setSelect(1)
        self.selectedSprite = sprite

    def onSelectSprite(self, event, onMouseObj):
        if onMouseObj:
            if self.selectedSprite:
                if onMouseObj != self.selectedSprite:
                    self.setNewSelectedSprite(onMouseObj)
            else:
                self.setNewSelectedSprite(onMouseObj)

            self.selectedSprite.setLastPos((event.GetX(),event.GetY()))
        else:
            self.removeSelectedSprite()

    def OnMouse(self, event):
        onMouseObj = self.checkCollide(event)
        event.Skip()

        if onMouseObj:
            onMouseObj.OnMouseHandler(event)

        if not event.GetSkipped():
            print "event dropped "
            return

        if event.LeftDown():
            self.onSelectSprite(event, onMouseObj)
        elif event.LeftUp():
            pass
        elif event.RightUp():
            self.onSelectSprite(event, onMouseObj)
        elif event.RightDown():
            self.onSelectSprite(event, onMouseObj)
        elif event.Dragging() and event.LeftIsDown():
            if self.selectedSprite:
                self.selectedSprite.move((event.GetX(),event.GetY()))

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        self.Redraw()
        event.Skip()  # Make sure the parent frame gets told to redraw as well

    def OnSize(self, event):
        self.size = self.GetSizeTuple()
        self.size_dirty = True

    def Kill(self, event):
        self.Unbind(event=wx.EVT_PAINT, handler=self.OnPaint)
        self.Unbind(event=wx.EVT_TIMER, handler=self.Update, source=self.timer)

    def onZoomIn(self):
        self.zoomRatio += 0.2
        self.onZoomUpdate()

    def onZoomReset(self):
        self.zoomRatio = 1
        self.onZoomUpdate()

    def onZoomOut(self):
        if self.zoomRatio > 0.2:
            self.zoomRatio -= 0.2
        self.onZoomUpdate()

    def onZoomUpdate(self):
        self.zoomUpdateBackground(self.zoomRatio)
        for s in self.rootSpriteGroup.sprites():
            s.onZoomUpdate(self.zoomRatio)


class TestFrame ( wx.Frame ):
    def __init__( self, parent, fSize ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = fSize, style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        fgSizer1 = wx.FlexGridSizer( 2, 1, 0, 0 )
        fgSizer1.AddGrowableCol( 0 )
        fgSizer1.AddGrowableRow( 0 )
        fgSizer1.SetFlexibleDirection( wx.VERTICAL )
        fgSizer1.SetNonFlexibleGrowMode( wx.FLEX_GROWMODE_ALL )


        self.panelMain = MyHmiPanel(self, -1)

        fgSizer1.Add( self.panelMain, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_panel4 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        bSizer3 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

        self.bZoomIn = wx.Button( self.m_panel4, wx.ID_ANY, u"Zoom In", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer3.Add( self.bZoomIn, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.bReset = wx.Button( self.m_panel4, wx.ID_ANY, u"Reset", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer3.Add( self.bReset, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.bZoomOut = wx.Button( self.m_panel4, wx.ID_ANY, u"Zoom Out", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer3.Add( self.bZoomOut, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_panel4.SetSizer( bSizer3 )
        self.m_panel4.Layout()
        bSizer3.Fit( self.m_panel4 )
        fgSizer1.Add( self.m_panel4, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.SetSizer( fgSizer1 )
        self.Layout()
        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        self.bZoomIn.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onZoomIn )
        self.bReset.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onZoomReset )
        self.bZoomOut.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onZoomOut )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass

    def onZoomIn( self, event ):
        self.panelMain.onZoomIn()
        event.Skip()

    def onZoomReset( self, event ):
        self.panelMain.onZoomReset()
        event.Skip()

    def onZoomOut( self, event ):
        self.panelMain.onZoomOut()
        event.Skip()


if __name__=='__main__':
        app = wx.App(redirect=False)
        frame = TestFrame(None, (800, 600))
        frame.SetPosition((100, 100))
        frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thank @user3239580, I am going to this right now. (I have a `wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "!m_cols || idx < (size_t)m_cols" failed at ..\..\src\common\sizer.cpp(1980) in wxFlexGridSizer::AddGrowableCol(): invalid column index` do you know the reason ?)

Comment: sorry, please remove this line "fgSizer1.AddGrowableCol( 1 )", though it is working with my wxpython 2.8.12.1 and python 2.7.3

Comment: Then I get another `IndexError: tuple index out of range` if I remove this line. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Could you please show me your wxpython version and python version? I'll try with that.

Comment: I use Python 2.7 (x32) (on Windows 64), and I have both wxpython version 2.8 and 3.0 installed (I don't remember which one is called)

Comment: You can check "Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx.pth"

Comment: Just have a try with wxpython 3.0(x32), didn't see the error you mentioned

Comment: And please add back fgSizer1.AddGrowableCol(1) and change it back to fgSizer1.AddGrowableCol(0) if you are using wxpython 3.0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46262/discussion-between-basj-and-user3239580)

Comment: Still the same problem : File "D:\gui_tests\bounty.py", line 172, in setCurrentResource,     self.imageOnLoad = self.resizeResource(self.imageResource[status][4], (self.width, self.height)),      IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Is some other modules/image ressources etc. necessary in the same folder for this code to run ?

Comment: No. You can open the image resource with its path like "d:/image/bg.jpg". Is this demo working now?

Comment: It should be self.imageResource[status][1] in line 172. There is no other resource required to run this Demo.

Comment: Copy the code into one file without any change, directly run this file should be fine.

Comment: It works now : we need to replace [4] by [1] ; can you modify this in your answer ? Now I am going to see if I can implement my question with this (image, auto-resizing when resizing, etc.). Thank you already!

Comment: Sorry, I finally realized it is the error in the answer. It has been  corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the scaling issue, but an old trick I recall for doing the arbitrary image target hit-checking (no buttons required) goes like this:

1) Create a blank invisible image the same size as the visible one.

2) As you draw targets on the main image, draw an identically shaped "shadow" to the invisible with all the same value pixel (but a unique value for every target).  A "handle", if you will.

3) When you get a mouse click on the main image, use the coordinates to get the same pixel from your invisible shadow image.  The value will be the handle for the target.

Simple once you hear it, isn't it?